# How to exclude specific JSON objects when rendering data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, datatable

I have a local JSON file containing JSON objects and I want it so that if an obj *contains* a specific string, then that object is rendered to a table. If not, then it's not rendered. For the time being I'm getting one error in DevTools: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DT_RowId' of undefined` and I'm working with DataTables---while it is useful, using functions with it has been a headache.

#### JS snippet:

```
function loadPH() {
    let admissText = admissData.d.results.map(function(val) {
        if (val.p_h_v !== "") { // If this is not empty, then return
            return {
                "PHV": val.p_h_v,
                "Part C": val.partc
            }
        }
    })

    $('#prohac-table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: "PHV" },
            { data: "Part C" },
            ... // ---------- the rest contains irrelevant data
```

#### JSON snippet:

```
{
    "d": {
      "results": [
        {
         ...
         "p_h_v": "" // ------------ this doesn't meet conditions, isn't rendered
         ...
        },
        {
         "p_h_v": "Yes" // ---------- meets conditions---this obj rendered
         ...
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate the issue at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. `.map()` is not designed to filter elements from an `Array`. `'DT_RowId'` does not appear at the code at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted your example to a `stack-snippet` and all it took was a `filter`, the values that map wasn't returning were `undefined` objects in your dataset and were causing the issue.

```js
var admissData = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
        "p_h_v": "Maybe", // ---------- meets conditions---this obj rendered
        "partc": "show this too"
      },
      {
        "p_h_v": "", // ------------ this doesn't meet conditions, isn't rendered
        "partc": "test - no show"
      },
      {
        "p_h_v": "Yes", // ---------- meets conditions---this obj rendered
        "partc": "test - show"
      }
    ]
  }
};

function loadProHac() {
  let admissText = admissData.d.results
    .filter(x => x.p_h_v !== "")  //added your filter here.
    .map(function(val) {
      return {
        "PHV": val.p_h_v,
        "Part C": val.partc
      }
    });

  $('#prohac-table').DataTable({
    data: admissText,
    columns: [{
        data: "PHV"
      },
      {
        data: "Part C"
      }
    ]
  });
}
loadProHac();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id='prohac-table'></table>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Two takeaways I can get from this: 1. I was *headed* on the right path and my code needed tweaking, 2. `.map` being there and not `.filter` (I had it earlier...not sure why I removed it) should've been a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Array.filter()` is what you're looking for here:

```
const admissText = admissData.d.results.filter(result => result.p_h_v !== '');
```

Comment: Yeah... I had filter earlier but changed it to map for some reason. Will try this later tonight.